# Writing primtive ID per primitive in Geometry shader

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am a bit confused with the description of [gl_PrimitiveID](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/gl_PrimitiveID.xml).[Here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Built-in_Variable_%28GLSL%29#Geometry_shader_outputs) is said that

> The meaning for this value is whatever you want it to be. However, if
>   you want to match the standard OpenGL meaning (ie: what the Fragment
>   Shader would get if no GS were used), just do this for each vertex
>   before emitting it.: gl_PrimitiveID = gl_PrimitiveIDIn;

Does it mean that if I output a quad from geometry shader the fragment shader will get 0,1,2,3? What I need is to output gl_PrimitiveID once per primitive and not per vertex or triangle.Will this suffice?

```
 gl_PrimitiveID = gl_PrimitiveIDIn
```

If I write it only once before  EndPrimitive(); ?

Comment: Btw,anyone happened to see @NicolBolas ? The dude got lost already since September on all the networks.(SO -sorry)

Comment: Maybe he got a job ;)

Comment: Technically, any attribute that is output by a GS has an undefined value after you emit a vertex. It honestly would make no sense to emit this per-vertex, because what would happen if each of the 3 vertices in a triangle were given different primitive IDs? Interpolating the primitive ID during rasterization is a nonsensical operation. There is a concept of a provoking vertex and that is the ***only*** vertex where `gl_PrimitiveID` actually needs to be defined; in other words, the first/last vertex (depending on provoking mode) in a primitive is the one that defines the ID for the entire thing.

Comment: Also, how are you emitting a quad in a geometry shader? =P You only have three choices for primitive type: Point, Line Strip or Triangle Strip.